# How can i match a file and get its path and date in cygwin

Tags: ls, cygwin

`ls -R "all.xml"  //host1//dw/fold`
i am trying to use this command to find `all.xml` file in the `fold` directory and its subsequent directories but i am getting all the files present in that directory and its sub directories , is there any way i can find and list all the `all.xml` file with timestamp and its path using `ls` command

Answer (score 1):

On `bash`, leverage `globstar` for recursive directory traversal with glob pattern `**`:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls -l /path/to/fold/**/all.xml
```

Disable `globstar` (`shopt -u globstar`) or run the above in a subshell, if you want:

```
( shopt -s globstar && ls -l /path/to/fold/**/all.xml )
```

---

Or use `find` with `-ls` action to list the file attributes:

```
find /path/to/fold/ -type f -name all.xml -ls
```

Comment: how can i make it recursive and `shopt -s globstar` does not work in mine , because sorry i forgot to mention i using cygwin in windows

Comment: @kewin Use `find`: `find /path/to/fold/ -type f -name all.xml -ls` Or `find /path/to/fold/ -type f -name all.xml -exec ls -l {} +`

Answer (score 1):

As you on `cygwin` make sure that you are able to apply `bash`'s ***find*** command instead of Windows ***find*** command:

```
find //host1//dw/fold -type f -name "all.xml" -printf "%p\t%t\n"
```

---

- `%p` - File's name
- `%t` - File's last modification time in the format returned by the C `ctime` function

Comment: i get the error `find invalid switch`

Comment: @kewin, that's what I told you in my 1st sentence. Read this http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1659559-find-invalid-switch (and others), solve your `find` issue beforehand

Comment: told me?? i did not post that question in that post

Comment: and i am  using a cygwin cmd not a bash

Comment: @kewin, so you should have mentioned about your cygwin in your question